# AutoLISP Drawing Insert Scale from 1 point to another

Tags: autolisp

I have a routine that is designed to created an duct elbow in AutoCAD and then insert a turning vane.

I have the program working almost perfectly, it's just that when I go to insert the block I have it set so that the scale of the block is the cross-sectional distance from point 2 to point 5 (this is the inside corner and outside corner of the elbow respectively) and the inserted block is distorted horribly.

I don't know if there is a way to avoid this or not.

```
; Garrett Ford 6/23/17

; The purpose of this program is to allow the user to enter a few
; dimensions and then insert and elbow with a turning vane

(defun C:bow(/ oldsnap oldlayer oldblip flag iw fw tt rot ip ang bend p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 ss)
 ;***********************************************************************
    ; Save System Variables

    (setq oldsnap (getvar "osmode"))
    (setq oldlayer (getvar "clayer"))
    (setq oldblip (getvar "blipmode"))
 ;***********************************************************************
    ;Change Settings & User Input

    (setvar "osmode" 35)
    (setvar "blipmode" 0)
    (setq flag (tblsearch "Layer" "LP-DUCT")) ; checks for LP-DUCT
        (if flag
            (setvar "clayer" "LP-DUCT") ; changes layer to LP-DUCT
            (alert ("No LP-DUCT Layer!")) ; if layer doesn't exist fuction terminates
        )
    (setq iw (getdist "\nWhat is the Initial Width? : "))
    (setq fw (getdist "\nWhat is the Final Width? : "))
    (setq tt (getdist "\nWhat is the Throat Length: "))
    ;(setq rot (getangle "\nWhat is the Angle of Rotation? : "))
    (setq ip (getpoint "\nSelect an Insertion Point: "))
    (setq ang (getangle ip "\nWhat is the Initial Throat direction from the Insertion point?: "))
    (initget 1 "Left Right")
    (setq bend (if (= (getkword "\nBend direction [Left/Right]: ") "Right") - +))
;***********************************************************************
    ; Polar Calculations

    (setq p1 (polar ip (bend ang (/ pi 2)) (/ iw 2)))
    (setq p2 (polar p1 ang tt)) ; Inside Corner
    (setq p3 (polar p2 (bend ang (/ pi 2)) tt))
    (setq p4 (polar p3 ang fw))
    (setq p5 (polar p4 (bend ang (- (/ pi 2))) (+ tt iw)))  ;  Outside Corner
    (setq p6 (polar p5 (+ ang pi) (+ tt fw)))
 ;***********************************************************************
; Line & Insert Commands

    ;(setq ss (ssadd))
    (setvar "osmode" 0)
    (command "_.pline" ip p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 "_close")
    ;(ssadd (entlast) ss)
    (setvar "osmode" 7079)
    (command "_.insert" "tvain" p2 (distance p2 p5) (+ ang (/ pi 2)))
    ;(ssadd (entlast) ss)
    ;(command "rotate" ss "rot" ip pause)
    (setvar "osmode" oldsnap)
    (setvar "clayer" oldlayer)
    (setvar "blipmode" oldblip)
)   ; End Defun
;************************************************************************
    ;Converts the Degrees into Radians

(defun dtr (ang) ;define degrees to radians function
 (* pi (/ ang 180.0)) 
 ;divide the angle by 180 then
 ;multiply the result by the constant PI
) ;end of function
;************************************************************************
```

Comment: What is the problem? "block is distorted horribly" can You share some sample, preview of result and prepare expected result ? mark points p2, p5

Comment: I figured out the problem.
1. It wasn't set to scale uniformly
2. I needed the insert function to look like this, I was missing angtos
(command "_.insert" "tvain" "_s" (distance p2 p5) "_r" (angtos (angle p2 p5)) p2)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

- `(alert ("No LP-DUCT Layer!"))` will error.

  This should instead be:`(alert "No LP-DUCT Layer!")`
- You should test whether each of your `getXXX` calls (e.g. `getpoint`, `getdist` etc.) return a non-nil value before proceeding. Since in AutoLISP anything which is non-nil is considered a `True` result, this can be easily achieved using a combination of `if` and `and`, for example:

  ```
  (if
      (and
          (setq iw (getdist "\nWhat is the Initial Width? : "))
          (setq fw (getdist "\nWhat is the Final Width? : "))
          (setq tt (getdist "\nWhat is the Throat Length: "))
          (setq ip (getpoint "\nSelect an Insertion Point: "))
          (setq ang (getangle ip "\nWhat is the Initial Throat direction from the Insertion point?: "))
          ...
      )
      (progn
          ;; Do your thing
      )
  )
  ```

  Since AutoLISP supports short-circuit evaluation, the `and` function will cease evaluation of the arguments as soon as an expression returns `nil`. Hence, if the user does not provide a value for the *Initial Width*, the `and` expression will not be validated and they will not be prompted to specify the *Final Width*.
- I would suggest using the command-line version of the `INSERT` command by prefixing the command with a hyphen (i.e. `-INSERT`).

  I would also suggest explicitly specifying the scale & rotation using the keywords provided by this command, e.g.:

  ```
  (command "_.-insert" "tvain" "_S" (distance p2 p5) "_R" (angtos (+ ang (/ pi 2))) "_non" p2)
  ```

  The `angtos` function is required in this case as the `-INSERT` command (and indeed any command evaluated using the `command` function) uses the angular units set within the drawing, as opposed to radians.
- The `dtr` function defined in your code is not being evaluated and so may be omitted.
- Rather than setting the `OSMODE` system variable to `0`, you may want to use the following expression to set bit `16384`:

  ```
  (setvar 'osmode (logior 16384 (getvar 'osmode)))
  ```

  This is the equivalent of the user pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> to disable Object Snaps as opposed to setting `OSMODE` to `0`, which is the equivalent to the user unchecking all of the Object Snap modes in the dialog.

  This has the advantage that if your code errors for any reason (including if the user presses <kbd>Esc</kbd> during program execution), Object Snap will merely be disabled and may be re-enabled using <kbd>F3</kbd>, rather than wiping the user's Object Snap settings entirely.

  Alternatively, you can avoid changing the `OSMODE` system variable altogether and instead prefix your point inputs with the `"_non"` snap modifier (meaning 'none'), which causes AutoCAD to ignore all active snap modes for the next point input, e.g.:

  ```
  (command "_.pline" "_non" ip "_non" p1 ... etc ... "_close")
  ```

  Or, as another option, you could use a locally defined error handler which would reset the `OSMODE` system variable (and all other modified system variables) following an error in the code. I describe how to do this in my tutorial on [Error Handling](http://lee-mac.com/errorhandling.html).